# How to sort Appended <li>-items in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, sorting

I am very new to programming so please excuse, that this may be a trivial question, but so far I have not found a satisfying solution to my problem.

In my HTML Code I have an unordered list like this. These list elements are just there for testing purposes.

```
<ul id="WoodList">
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Catv</li>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
    <li>Car</li>
    <li>Pear</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Cat2</li>
    <li>Apple4</li>
    <li>Banana1</li>
    <li>Cat</li>
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Cat</li>
</ul>
```

I have an XML-File containing the trivial and scientific names of trees, that should be appended to the list and displayed in an alphabetical order.

```js
var activeLanguage = "de"

function buildList() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml/wooddata.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find('wood').each(function () {
                var trivialName = $(this).find("name[lang=" + activeLanguage + "]").text();
                var scientificName = $(this).find("scientific_name").text();                
                $("#WoodList").append("<li>" + trivialName + " (" + scientificName + ")</li>");
            });
        }
    });
};

function sortUL(selector) {
    var listItems = selector.children('li').get();
    console.log(listItems);
    $(listItems).sort(function (a, b) {
        var upA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
        var upB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
        return (upA < upB) ? -1 : (upA > upB) ? 1 : 0;
    }).appendTo(selector);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    buildList();
    sortUL("#WoodList");
});
```

Please excuse the strange indents, I was fighting a bit with the stackoverflow editor.

As you see, I have two functions. One that takes the elements from the xml-file and appends this contents to the html-list like this

```
<li>Spruce (Picea Abies)</li>
```

The next function should sort the list in an alphabetical order. And it is working to an certain extend. All the test-list-elements in the html are sorted totally correct, but the appended xml-list-items are always displayed at the end of the list without being sorted. It's probably just a small mistake, could you please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to execute the `sortList()` function after the AJAX request has returned:

```js
success: function (data) {
    $(data).find('wood').each(function () {
        var trivialName = $(this).find("name[lang=" + activeLanguage + "]").text();
        var scientificName = $(this).find("scientific_name").text();
        $("#WoodList").append("<li>" + trivialName + " (" + scientificName + ")</li>");
    });
    sortUL("#WoodList");
}
```

Then you can optimise the sort function, like this:

```js
function sortUL(selector) {
    var $ul = $(selector);
    $ul.find('li').sort(function (a, b) {
        var upA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
        var upB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
        return (upA < upB) ? -1 : (upA > upB) ? 1 : 0;
    }).appendTo(selector);
};
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/t5a4gy1z/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used your optimised sort function

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute your sort function every time after you finish appending new li tags

Answer (score 1):

You should be sorting the list after appending the `< li >` as well inside the `success : function(){}`.

```
var activeLanguage = "de"

    function buildList() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "xml/wooddata.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (data) {
                $(data).find('wood').each(function () {

                    var trivialName = $(this).find("name[lang=" + activeLanguage + "]").text();
                    var scientificName = $(this).find("scientific_name").text();

                    $("#WoodList").append("<li>" + trivialName + " (" + scientificName + ")</li>");
                });
                sortUL("#WoodList");  // Call it here.
            }
        });
    };


$(document).ready(function () {
    buildList();
    sortUL("#WoodList");

});
```

`sortUL` in `$(document).ready()` won't sort the appended elements because the AJAX call takes some time to execute and before it's execution the sortUL will be called.